# Macro Cannot See Open Workbook from Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am running a macro from an excel workbook on my local machine, and at the end of it the macro copies a set of data and pastes it in a log that is in a separate workbook.  I can get it working fine when the log is on my local machine, but I am having trouble getting it to copy data to the log when the workbook is stored on the company sharepoint server.  I have both files open in excel (with edit permissions on the sharepoint based file), but when I try to open the workbook it fails.  Trying to diagnose the problem I even had the macro spit out a list of all the open excel files at the moment and it does not seem to list the sharepoint baesd file (despite it obviously being open at the moment).  Any ideas on how I can access this file?  I don't necessarily need it to open the file on its own, I am more than happy to go into sharepoint manually and open the file, I just can't get the data to copy across for some reason.  Any help that could be provided would be most appreciated, thanks in advance!

The line of code causing the problem is:
Set logbook = Application.Workbooks("Log")
Where the file name is Log.xlsx and that file is open in excel at the time the macro is running.
The error I get is:
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Can you attach the error message (if any) and an extract of the code?

Comment: My apologies, the error I get is:
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
The line of code causing the problem is 
Set logbook = Application.Workbooks("Log")
I have the Log.xlsx file that is on sharepoint open at the time I am running this, and again, no issues when the Log.xlsx file is on my local machine stored in a random (different) folder.

Comment: Always safer to use the file name *including* the extension.  Is it possible the file is open in a separate instance of Excel?

Comment: it would be helpful to have more code. How are you opening the sharepoint file? Are you setting an excel application object?

Comment: Thanks for the initial feedback, I added the file extension but still encounter the same error (but will leave it to make it safer).  It does look like it is in a separate instance of Excel, so what do I need to do to access it?  With regards to opening the sharepoint file, I am actually going into sharepoint and opening the file in edit mode before I run this macro, the macro is not tasked with that work.

Comment: It will be much easier if you open your macro in the same instance as the SharePoint workbook.  You *can* refer to workbooks in a different Excel instance, but it's not straightforward at all.  I can post an example if you need it but don't ask me to explain exactly how it works ;-)